# resizable prop no longer working in react-big-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-dom, react-big-calendar

I was building a scheduling app with react-big-calendar and I have noticed from React v17 onwards the resizable does not work because of the way react handles event changing.

this is the issue: https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues/1785

I have seen in the comments that someone fixed this issue and made a pull request: https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/pull/1857

My problem is that it is still not working, the resizable handles does not show up on the big calendar. I made sure I am using the latest version 0.33.6 and also tried to figure out where the user did the changes to events to fix the issue so that I can modify the package, but I noticed they both are completely different files, I wasn't able to find the event handlers in my node_modules/react-big-calendar so that I can make edits. So how do I fix this error? I cannot revert back to reactv16 because I must use v17 in my project.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Here's what my calendar looks like:

```
<DragAndDropCalendar
        selectable
        resizable
        onEventDrop={onEventDrop}
        onEventResize={resizeEvent}
        localizer={localizer}
        events={events}
        onSelectSlot={handleSelect}
        defaultView="week"
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        timeslots={2}
        step={15}
        popup
        tooltipAccessor={(e) => e.title}
      />
    </div>
```